# for, If true, If a = b copy

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = 2 To finalrow
   If Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "" & Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -3).Value <> "" Then
     If Cells(i, 14) = Vlot Then
       Sheet7.Range(Cells(i, 14)).Copy
       Sheet7.Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
     End If
Next i
```

I keep getting a next without for error. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: You've not terminated your first `IF` with an `END IF`

Comment: `And` operator, not `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one :)

```
For i = 2 To 8
   If Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "" And Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -3).Value <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 14) = Vlot Then
          Sheet7.Range(Cells(i, 14)).Copy
          Sheet7.Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    End If
Next i
```